# How to create table from result of client side function \crosstabview

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

In psql i can get the pivot of a table using the client side function \crosstabview, but i can't figure out how to store the result in a table, i tried CREATE Table foo AS ... \crosstabview, but it stores just the input to the function and not the output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+and+([crosstab]+or+[pivot])

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the comment but crosstab funct doesn't work for me since i need a dynamic solution where i won't have to specify the output columns and their type in the AS ( .. ) clause. Because i have too many columns and they may change over time when i need to update results in the future.

Comment: That's not possible. One fundamental restriction of SQL is that the number, names and data types of all columns of a SQL query must be know _before_ that query is actually executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\crosstabview` is a psql slash command which takes the results of the actual query (everything up until `\crosstabview`) and reformats it. As such the output you see is generated within the psql client for display only, and cannot be used in other SQL operations.

To create a table based off the results of a crosstab query you'll need the [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) extension.